# Editar linha em um arquivo .class e recompilar

Tags: java

Possuo um arquivo chamado WEB.class que importei de um arquivo.WAR onde possue as strings para conexão ao nosso banco de dados com o seguinte codigo:

```
@Produces({"application/json"})
   @GET
   @Path("/ZoomNotasFiscais")
   public Response ZoomNotasFiscais(@QueryParam("empresa") String empresa, @QueryParam("codCliente") String codCliente, @QueryParam("loja") String loja, @QueryParam("search")) {
     try {
       sql = new SQL("cliente");
       Parametros parametros = new Parametros();
       try {
         String query = "SELECT D2_DOC AS [NF], SUM(SD2.D2_TOTAL + SD2.D2_VALIPI + SD2.D2_DESCON ) AS [VALOR] FROM " +
```

A unica coisa que eu preciso fazer é adicionar um novo campo na consulta do banco dentro da string query. Exemplo:

```
String query = "SELECT NOVO_CAMPO AS [NOVOCAMPO], D2_DOC AS [NF], SUM(SD2.D2_TOTAL + SD2.D2_VALIPI + SD2.D2_DESCON ) AS [VALOR] FROM " +
```

A unica duvida que tenho é como alterar essa linha do arquivo WEB.class e salvar novamente como WEB.class

Eu já fiz o download dos decompiladores e consegui enxergar o codigo, mas nenhum dele tem a opção para editar o codigo e salvar novamente esse arquivo .CLASS

Como alterar apenas essa linha e adicionar o .class novamente no projeto?
Preciso criar um novo arquivo .java?